# Functions and trigonometry.

Tags: functions

We learn in trigonometry that $\sin x \equiv \sin(\pi − x)$. Hence $f(\sin x) = f(\sin[\pi − x])$. Now let $f(x) = x\sin x$. Then $x\sin x = (\pi − x)\sin(\pi − x)$ or $x = \pi − x$. Hence $\pi = 2x$ and since $x$ is any value we choose, so is $\pi$. What is wrong?

Comment: $f(x) = f(\pi-x)$ is not true in general.

Comment: You can replace $\sin{x}$ with $\sin{(\pi-x)}$ but you cannot replace $x$ with $(\pi-x)$ in general.

Comment: @PM2Ring This actually has nothing to do with whether the $\sin$ function is one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=x\sin x\implies f(\sin x)=\sin x\sin(\sin x)$ and $f(\sin(\pi-x))=\sin(\pi-x)\sin(\sin(\pi-x))=f(\sin x)$.